# Clone separate / and home to larger drive

Tags: partitioning, home-directory, clone

I currently have 23.04 installed on a 500Gb SSD, with separate root (50Gb) and Home (450Gb). Both partitions are filling up so I plan to get a larger SSD.

If I create two partitions on the new SSD (say 80Gb for root and the rest for Home), will I be able to simply clone the old partitions to the new ones using a tool like Clonezilla? Or will the different sizes create issues? Will the root partition be able to easily find Home? Not ethat nothing else about the system will change - I simply plan to switch out the old SDD for a larger one.

Comment: There are also fast, simple, and safe alternatives to cloning for most users.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS install? Old MBR or gpt partitioning? Gpt bit harder to clone. Often easier to do new install & restore from your normal backup. Good way to confirm you backup has everything while you still have old drive to recovery anything missed in backup. You can export list of installed apps to make it easy to reinstall them & just rsync /home to new partition. If you mount /home using Something to install, everything user related will be there. If server type apps those need to be restored from backup.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. Alternatively you can just clone the entire disk with Clonezilla and then grow/move the partitions on the larger target disk. You will likely need to adjust your `/etc/fstab` to give it the right `UUID` for your new partition layout.

One simple way to discover the UUIDs is `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid` and you'll see each UUID as a link to the actual partition, like this:

```shell
alan@ziggy:~$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 May  5 12:55 0407-0201 -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May  5 12:55 3b5ee9ec-8e02-4da2-b08f-2a02b15d2821 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 May  5 12:46 96c77f27-d90f-4d14-a5d5-59ac57b3f6dc -> ../../nvme0n1p3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 May  5 12:46 B5CD-A7EE -> ../../nvme0n1p1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 May  5 12:47 B5F4-A0DD -> ../../nvme0n1p2
```